# Android How to add setOnEditorActionListener to List of EditTexts

Tags: android, android-edittext

i have fragment with 5 editTexts that i add dynamiclly:

```
 List<TextView> ArrayQuestionsEditTexts =new ArrayList<TextView>();

 for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
       View to_add = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_add_new_offer,
                        options_layout,false);

                EditText question = (EditText) 
                to_add.findViewById(R.id.editTextQuestion);

                ArrayQuestionsEditTexts.add(question);

                options_layout.addView(to_add);
 }
```

i want that when the user click next button in the keyboard to deliver the focus to the next edittext in the list ArrayQuestionsEditTexts.

i try that:

```
             for (int i = 0; i < ArrayQuestionsEditTexts.size()-1; i++) {
                final int nextItem = i+1;
                ArrayQuestionsEditTexts.get(i).setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                        if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)) {
                            ArrayQuestionsEditTexts.get(nextItem).requestFocus();

                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
           }
```

but this solution d'ont work.

Comment: Use `setTag` to set an incremental tag when you add edit texts. Then use `findViewWithTag()` to find the edit text when you need to request focus.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List<TextView> ArrayQuestionsEditTexts = new ArrayList<TextView>();

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    View to_add = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_add_new_offer, options_layout,false);

    EditText question = (EditText) to_add.findViewById(R.id.editTextQuestion);

    question.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)) {
                ArrayQuestionsEditTexts.get(nextItem).requestFocus();

            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    ArrayQuestionsEditTexts.add(question);

    options_layout.addView(to_add);
}
```

Or, in other words, when you do the first loop to inflate the layouts, why not also attach the listeners in that loop? Rather than looping a second time to add the listeners?

Comment: You have set an id on the layout components right? Otherwise findViewById will return null....

Answer (score 0):

according to the official [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) :

you need to `setTag` on view(which is edit text here) and then you need to find that view by using `findViewWithTag` after that you need to focus on edit text via `requestFocus`